# Debug with release(my own) keystore

Tags: android, titanium, keystore

I am using titanium.

Normally, I compile like this and check the debug log in console.

> ti build --T device --P android

It doesn't require any keystore (maybe titanium default keystore for debugging is used??)

However, I would like to use my own keystore file because google map requires original keystore file to show the map.

How can I debug with release keystore???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run

```
ti build --help
```

and see the options.   Use -K or --keystore to specify the keystore.

That being said, you can run keytool against the default developer keystore and register it will Google api and list it in you tiapp.xml.

Comment: Thank you very much , it works perfectly. I tried only ti --help, I should have tried ti build --help.